# How can call this function on jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to capture click event both on appended and not appended button my code.
 So i created a function named processClick()used:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.btn').on('click', function(e) {
        processClick($(this));
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});

$(document).on('click',".btn", function(e){
        processClick($(this));  
        e.preventDefault();
});

function processClick(thisObj) {
var $this = thisObj;
    //CODE HERE
}
```

How can i pass $(this) to my function? My code is not working, the page is refreshing after i click any .btn on my page. Thanks!

Comment: *"is refreshing after i click any .btn"* please, show us some of your html, try to create a [mcve]

Comment: I think the problem is in your html code.. show me the button code html

Comment: Any errors in the console? If your function is failing, `preventDefault` will never be reached, you should call it before calling your function. Also, you should not need the first click handler, just the second one will do (and in fact your function will fire twice, since propagation isn't stopped).

Comment: What happens if you put `e.preventDefault();` *before* `processClick($(this));`?

Comment: My code is working when i put the code inside processClick() to  $(document).ready(function() {}); and $(document).on('click',".btn", function(e){}); i actually coded it on $(document).ready(function() {}); but i noticed that the code is not working on appended button that's why i used also $(document).ready(function() {});, but i decided to use function.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#buttons').append('<button type="button" class="btn" id="button1">Click Me!</button>'); 

  $('.btn').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    processClick($(this));
  });
  
  function processClick(button) {
    console.log(button);
  }
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="buttons">
  <button type="button" class="btn" id="button2">Click Me!</button>
<div>
```